# How to read a file from s3 in EMR?

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-s3, elastic-map-reduce

I would like to read a file from S3 in my EMR Hadoop job. I am using the Custom JAR option.

I have tried two solutions:

- `org.apache.hadoop.fs.S3FileSystem`: throws a `NullPointerException`.
- `com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client`: throws an exception, saying "Access denied".

What I fail to grasp is that I am starting the job from the Console, so obviously I should have the necessary permissions. However, the AWS_*_KEY keys are missing from the environment variables (`System.getenv()`) that are available to the mapper.

I am sure I do something wrong, just not sure what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your EMR cluster need to have access to S3, you can create an IAM role for your EMR cluster and give it access to S3.
check this link : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-iam-roles.html

Comment: This was the right way to go. Without roles, the only solution is to write the access keys directly into the code (or a file in the jar, etc.). Using roles worked without danger of exposing the credentials.

Answer (score 4):

Probably a little bit late, but...
Use `InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider` for AmazonS3Client.

Comment: Why did this get a down vote is beyond me, very helpful.

Comment: This is life saving

Answer (score 0):

I think the syntax is

```
hadoop jar your.jar com.your.main.Class -Dfs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId=<access-id> -Dfs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey=<secrect-key>
```

Then the path to the common prefix you wish to read should be of the form

```
s3n://bucket-name/common/prefix/path
```

Comment: I am running the JAR on EMR. I do not have a `hadoop` command there, as far as I know.

Comment: EMR sucks ... get a devops to build you a proper EC2 cluster :) @DavidNemeskey

Comment: `hadoop` command is present in EMR instances (at least in version 5.3.0)